# Create a fixed size 3D array of strings in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am completely new to c++. Reading docs, to create an array of strings, I can do:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
...

std::vector<std::string> mylist;
```

But what if I want a fixed sized 3D array? ie, `mylist[10][20][30]`?

I tried:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>> mylist(10)(20)(30);
```

But this is throwing many compile errors with `(` being a wrong token.

Comment: `std::string mylist[10][20][30];`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Would using the string vector be better? Because I don't have to handle deleting it afterwards

Comment: but you want vectors right? or contiguous memory?

Comment: @tempomax You do not have to delete a static array when done.  It is an automatic object and will get cleaned up.

Comment: @NathanOliver What about a very large array? Like `mylist[10000][10000][10000]`? Then using vectors won't cause a stackoverflow quite so easily?

Comment: You should prefer `std::array` if you want fixed size.

Comment: @tempomax If it is very large then yes you need a vector or you run out of stack space.

Comment: 'std::vector<std::array<std::array<std::string, 30>, 20>> vec(10)' will both be guaranteed to allocated in heap (not stack) and will be put into contigious memory.